# Springboot - call function from controller and not xml file

Tags: xml, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Im rendering a Webpage using Thymeleaf variables and Spring Boot. There is an xml file initializing some functions in the controller that allows me to render the variables with Thymeleaf.

I'm trying to get rid of the XML file and call the variables from the controller but without success :/

Here's the XML file expression:

```
<on-start>
  <evaluate expression="testController.initPage(currentUser.id)"/>
</on-start>

<view-state id="fas" view="folder/webpage" model="model1">
  <on-entry>
    <evaluate expression="testController.initInfo(model1)"/>
  </on-entry>
</view-state>
```

Here's what I tried in the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/webpage")
public ModelAndView somewebpage(HttpServletRequest req, @AuthenticationPrincipal User user,
                                RedirectAttributes redir) {
    User theUser = null;
    boolean auth = false;

    if (user == null) {
        theUser = (User) req.getSession().getAttribute("user");
    } else {
        theUser = user;
        auth = true;
    }

    Long userId = theUser.getId();
    if (userId == null) {
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:403");
    }

    initPage(userId);
    Model1 model1 = new Model1();
    initInfo(model1);

    if (authenticated) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:webpage");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The redirect should be folder/webpage

```
ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:/folder/webpage");
```